# Dojo mobile EdgeToEdgeList tutorial not displaying

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, widget

I am trying to learn Dojo 1.9, having previously used 1.4.x. Been looking at some tutorials, and was trying out some examples of the dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList. I just don't seem to get it.

Having copied the sample code from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList.html they have for declarative (CSS sprite example) using CDN hosted dojo toolkit. However nothing gets displayed except a default HTML unordered List with 3 bullets, styled with the dojo mobile styles. Same behavior in both Chrome and FF 22.0 browsers. I see that there are no Network or Console errors, it just doesn't appear to load. I suspect I am missing something somewhere. Is there an onLoad attribute I need to specify somewhere?

Here is my example HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>
      MyTitle
    </title>
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="keywords" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>
        My Title
      </h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
        <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"
               data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
  "dojox/mobile",
  "dojox/mobile/parser"
]);
    </script>

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList"
    data-dojo-props='iconBase:"all-icons.png"'>
  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
      data-dojo-props='iconPos:"0,0,29,29"'>Airplane Mode
      <div class="mblItemSwitch" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Switch"></div></li>
  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
      data-dojo-props='iconPos:"0,29,29,29",
                       rightText:"mac",
                       href:"test_IconContainer.html"'>Wi-Fi</li>
  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
      data-dojo-props='iconPos:"0,58,29,29",
                       rightText:"AcmePhone",
                       moveTo:"general"'>Carrier</li>
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EdgeToEdgeList renders when I add parseOnLoad: true to the data-dojo-config attribute for loading dojo from CDN

E.g.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"
           data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

Edit: A more complete answer after doing research. The reason the code in my original question didn't work is that I was using the Declarative style for my EdgeToEdgeList widget, according to this in the [Dojo 1.9 documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/declarative/) parsing of the DOM is required when using the declarative method. However, although parseOnLoad: true worked in my case, this is not the best practice.

> Now, what we need to do is invoke the dojo/parser. Before the adoption
>   of AMD in Dojo 1.7 you could safely use a Dojo configuration option of
>   parseOnLoad: true. Now though, there are a few edge cases where you
>   could run into unexpected results if you use that, therefore it is now
>   recommended to invoke the parser discreetly in your code. So to run
>   the parser, you would want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dojo/dojo.js"
    data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button"],
    function(parser, ready){
        ready(function(){
            parser.parse();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using the new approach exactly as they have it works. It begs the question why their tutorial code doesn't illustrate this, but in any case, this is the answer to my original question.